# Android ArrayList size set to zero after call

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, arraylist, parse-platform

I'm currently working on a basic application that makes a query to parse (back4app) backend, the aim is to retrive ParseGeoPoint from every row in the class "Annuncio" and display them in the google map.
The query works fine, I have an ArrayList that is populated after the query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Keys.CLASS_NAME);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(ParseObject object : objects){

                    createAnnuncio(object);
                }
                progressDialog.hide();

            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

the createAnnuncio method is this:

```
 private void createAnnuncio(ParseObject object) {

    Azienda azienda = new Azienda();
    azienda.setWebSite(object.getString(Keys.SITO_WEB));
    azienda.setEmail(object.getString(Keys.EMAIL));
    azienda.setPhoneNumber(object.getString(Keys.TELEFONO));
    azienda.setLocation(object.getParseGeoPoint(Keys.LOCATION));
    azienda.setNomeAzienda(object.getString(Keys.NOME_AZIENDA));
    azienda.setDescAzienda(object.getString(Keys.DESC_AZIENDA));

    Annuncio annuncio = new Annuncio();
    annuncio.setAzienda(azienda);
    annuncio.setCompleteText(object.getString(Keys.TESTO_ANNUNCIO));
    annuncio.setJobKind(object.getString(Keys.TIPO_LAVORO));
    annuncio.setSettore(object.getString(Keys.SETTORE));
    annuncio.setTitolo(object.getString(Keys.TITOLO_ANNUNCIO));
    annuncio.setFineAnnuncio(object.getDate(Keys.FINE_ANNUNCIO));

    mAnnunci.add(annuncio);

}
```

Basically mAnnunci is a global variable:

```
public List<Annuncio> mAnnunci = new ArrayList<>();
```

Even the debug works fine, i have just 2 rows and the mAnnunci.size() is 2 after the for cycle in the query, but then the debugger takes me to some native code of parse sdk and i don't know why but after the query mAnnunci is empty.

```
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    showSpinner();

    getAllPostsFromParse(); // retrive all posts from parse backend
    //inside getAllPostsFromParse the size is 2
    setUpMarkers(); // here the size is 0 (the debug print is the first instruction, so I don't modify it)


}
```

And most of all sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Are you sure you populate your list before calling setupmarkers? Because the parse query is done in the backround and looking at how you're doing it it seems you're not waiting for it to finish... Sei sicuro che popoli la lista prima di chiamare setupmarkers? perche la query di parse e fatta in background e da come lo stai usando non mi sembra aspetti abbia completato.

Comment: I mean getAllPostFromParse does fire the first code block you posted? If yes the onDone callback is probably called after setUpMarkers. Quello che voglio dire e getAllPostFromParse chiama il codice postato nel primo blocco? se si la callback onDone viene probabilmente chiamata dopo a setUpMarkers

Comment: Hai perfettamente ragione! La chiamata alla funzione setUpMarkers veniva eseguita prima della chiamata asincrona, che errore stupido! Grazie mille, mi hai risparmiato un sacco di tempo a brancolare nel buio